# Yarn + Lerna + Angular Libs = broken publishing?

Tags: angularjs, yarnpkg, lerna

reHi!

Here's the deal, we have a monorepo. We're using Lerna & Yarn with a bunch of Angular Libraries.

In every package.json for the packages/libraries, we have something like:

`"prepublishOnly": "yarn build <library name goes here>"`

The way Yarn works for workspaces is `yarn install`, does what it does. Because we use workspaces, it creates *symlinks* to the packages. For example, if we have a package called `@foo/bar`, in the top-level `node_modules`, we would have `node_modules/@foo/bar` be a symlink to `libs/foo-bar`.

Yarn Workspaces is all fine and dandy, except the stuff in `node_modules/@foo/bar` isn't ready to be published. First, we need to build the package using Angular CLI's compiler.

We accomplish that with the already mentioned `prepublishOnly` script in `package.json`.

What works is when *all* the packages need are to be built. The flow goes:

1. `yarn install` - Does the symlink/workspace magic.
2. `lerna publish --contents dist` - Does the monorepo magic. Lerna will see that all the packages have had modifications, and run the `prepublishOnly` across all the packages. This way, what's in `node_modules/@foo` will be "legit" NPM packages (the output of Angular CLI building the libraries)

The problem is when a single library has a modification.

1. `yarn install` - Does the symlink/workspace magic. All the things in `node_modules/@foo` will be symlinks to `libs/<package-name>` which, at this point, are source files. Not NPM packages
2. `lerna publish --contents dist` - Starts... and goes "Oh, only Package A has changed. So let me run against it." Lerna will fail due to the other packages inside `node_modules` NOT being legit NPM packages.

I need to figure out how to either:

1. Always build all the packages when doing a publish OR
2. Somehow use packages from the NPM registry during the build process

I feel like I'm missing something simple somewhere.

If there are examples I can give to help explain, please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Always build all the packages when doing a publish

in your root package.json (considering you've lerna as a dev dependency)

```json
{
 "scripts": {
     "publish-ci": "lerna run build && lerna publish --content dist"
  }
}
```

in your library1 packages

```json
 "scripts": {
     "build": "yarn build library1"
  }
```

now you can run `yarn publish-ci` on your root folder and everything will be built and published.

you could also use `lerna publish --from-package` flag to publish only changed package.

### Somehow use packages from the NPM registry during the build process

Here, you need lerna to only changed packages, not for publishing, a hacky way to get this is

in your root package.json

```json
{
 "scripts": {
     "publish-ci": "node custom.publish.js"
  }
}
```

in custom.publish.js

```js
var { execSync } = require("child_process");
let packagesChangedString = execSync("yarn lerna changed --toposort --json --loglevel silent").toString();
let packageChanged = JSON.parse(packagesChangedString.substring(packagesChangedString.indexOf("["), packagesChangedString.lastIndexOf("]") + 1));
console.log(packageChanged);

packageChanged.forEach(changed => {
    // exec npm publish manually without using lerna for publishing. 
    execSync("cd " + changed.location + " && npm publish" );

});
```